# Can all positive real polynomials be expressed as a sum of polynomial squares?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

For $P(x)=y$,   where $P(x)$ is some real polynomial strictly above the $x$-axis, can it be expressed as the sum of polynomial squares?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventeenth_problem

Comment: @lhf That's about multivariate polynomials

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, the homogenous version of $P$ has two variables.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question.  However $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ seems to be a counterexample.  Min is $f(-1)=1$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg $f(x)=(x+\frac12)^2+\sqrt{\frac34}^2$. Thoug I'm not sure what *linear* squares should mean

Comment: Linear as in the x in the bracket's shouldn't be sqrt(x); since you could just take every term and stick it to the power of half and square it

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $x^{2}+\sqrt{x}^{2}+\sqrt{1}^{2}$; I just wanted to prevent this

Comment: @yolo So, sum of squares of (real) polynomials in $x$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen; I suppose so; I'll edit now; (though I am curious to see if there is a proof to counteract solely linear squares)

Comment: If I'm correct, $x^4 + 1$ couldn't be expressed as such a sum, since a sum of that form would have to have strictly positive second derivative everywhere or else be constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $P(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ is such that $P(x)\geqslant 0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $P(x)$ cannot have odd-degree roots in $\mathbb{R}$ (otherwise it would change its sign in a neighborhood of such a root). Hence each of its roots is either even-degree real one, or comes in a pair with its complex-conjugate. In other words, $$P(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n\big((x-a_k)^2+b_k^2\big)$$ for some real $a_k$ and $b_k$ for $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$. But $$(A^2+B^2)(C^2+D^2)=(AC+BD)^2+(AD-BC)^2,$$ hence (by induction on $n$) $P(x)=A^2(x)+B^2(x)$ for some polynomials $A(x)$ and $B(x)$.

Comment: This is the well-known proof.  Now all we need to know is what the OP means by an **algebraic** polynomial

Comment: The "algebraic" should clearly be discarded. And yes, I'm sure it's a duplicate (but didn't find it out yet).

Comment: Strictly speaking, you also need to prove that complex-conjugate roots have equal multiplicities :) (Of course, this is rather easy, e.g., by dividing our $P\left(x\right)$ by $\left(x-r\right)\left(x-\overline r\right)$ and arguing that the result is again a nonnegative polynomial and therefore must have either both or none of $r$ and $\overline r$ as roots.)

Answer (score 0):

If "sum of linear squares" means
$$
P(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n (a_jx+b_j)^2,
\tag1$$
then the answer is no.  For example $x^4+1$ is not of that form.  Indeed, for anything of the form $(1)$ we have
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{P(x)}{x^4+1} = 0
$$

Comment: Apologies; I've appeared to make an error with my question which I was just editing as you posted your answer. Though this is a really curious proof

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We induct on the degree. If $P$ is constant we are done. Otherwise we must have the degree of $P$ be even and the limit of $P$ is infinity in both $\pm \infty$ dirrections. Hence there exists an $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $P$ obtains it's minimum value at $a$.  But then $(x - a)^2$ divides $P(x) - P(a)$. Thus we can write

$$P(x) = (x-a)^2 \frac{P(x) - P(a)}{(x-a)^2} + \sqrt{P(a)}^2$$ and by inductive hypothesis $\frac{P(x) - P(a)}{(x-a)^2}$ can be written as the sum of polynomial squares so we are done.